# join array from foreach loop and making multiple array where array key is empty

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

`I want to join all keys together and make multiple array where key is repeating.This is the following result coming from foreach loop and i want to make it like i have show in below expected result.`

```
Array
(
    [band] => 40m
    [call] => VP6D
)
Array
(
    [freq] => 7.056305
)
Array
(
    [mode] => FT8
)
Array
(
    [operator] => N4FN
)
Array
(
    [band] => 15m
    [call] => VP6D
)
Array
(
    [freq] => 21.077790 

)
Array
(
    [mode] => RTTY
)
Array
(
    [operator] => N4FN
)
Array
(
    [rst_rcvd] => 59
    [rst_sent] => 59
)
```

expected result: i want to make like this in another array where i can make it like to put in csv using fputcsv function in php. how to merge it so that i can achieve the desired result like below

```
    array(
        array('band'=> 40m,'call'=>VP6D,'freq' => 7.05,...),
        array('band'=> 15m,'call'=>VP6D,'freq' => 21.0777,...)
    )
```

These are my tags:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a_index:3>
    [1] => <ant_az:3>
    [2] => <ant_el:3>
    [3] => <band:3>
    [4] => <band_rx:3>
    [5] => <call:4>
    [6] => <cnty:4>
    [7] => <comment:23>
)
```

and these are my tags values, i used pregmatchall and found 0 key of tag and value.

```
(
    [0] => 0.0
    [1] => 0.0
    [2] => 0.0
    [3] => 40m
    [4] => 40m
    [5] => VP6D
    [6] => Pima
    [7] => FT8
    [8] => 03
    [9] => 06 

)
```

and i used foreach on them:

```
$i = 0;
            $newArray = array();
            foreach ($tags as $value) {
                $result = explode(':', trim($value, '<>'));
                $newKey = $result[0];
                $new_val = "";
                if (isset($tagValue[$i])) {
                    $new_val = $tagValue[$i];
                }
                if (in_array($newKey, $head)) {
                    $newArray[$newKey] = $new_val;
                }
                $i++;
            }
```

Comment: based on what are you identify mode or freq?

Comment: It looks like you probably have another loop around this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for your problem.

```
//Modify this to init your multiple arrays
            $a["band"] = "40m";
            $a["call"] = "VP6D";
            $b["freq"] = 7.056305;
            $c["mode"] = "FT8";
            $d["operator"] = "N4FN";
            $e["band"] = "15m";
            $f["call"] = 'VP6D';
            $g['freq'] = 21.077790;
            $h['mode'] = 'RTTY';
            $i['operator'] = 'N4FN';
            $j['rst_rcvd'] = 59;
            $j['rst_sent'] = 59;
            $result[] = $a;
            $array = [$b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j];
//Modify this to init your multiple arrays
            foreach ($array as $singleArray) {
                $index = 0;
                foreach ($singleArray as $key => $value) {
                    if (!array_key_exists($key, $result[$index])) {
                        foreach ($singleArray as $keyRes => $valueRes) {
                            $result[$index][$keyRes] = $valueRes;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    while (isset($result[$index]) && array_key_exists($key, $result[$index])) {
                        $index++;
                    }
                    foreach ($singleArray as $keyRes => $valueRes) {
                        $result[$index][$keyRes] = $valueRes;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $this->json(['data' => $result]);
```

[image]